# Is baking the skates equivalent of quicker breaking them in?

Tags: equipment, skating, maintenance

Will baking give me something that (after some time) breaking in will give me as well? Or will it be completely "new quality" not reachable by simply skating (even for long period)?

If the latter, is baking a must just right after shopping, or one can skate, say, for a week and then bake the skate. This is safer for potential selling skates.

*I have Bauer Supreme One.7 and Vapor X.70 in mind.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baking skates essentially gives you a step ahead in the skate breaking in status. If you don't bake them, your skates will still form to your foot, however it will take longer.

Baking can be done at any time, and can also be done multiple times. It can be good to bake the skates before your first skate, and again after 2-3 skates.